# html5 video dont working

Tags: html, iis-7

```
    <video height=600 width=800 controls >
<source type="video/mp4" src="video1.mp4"/>
<source type="video/ogg" src="video1.ogg"/>
<source type="video/webm" src="video1.webm"/>
</video>
```

I've added mime type video/mp4 on iss.
in chrome this video working.but it dosnt work in iexplorer10.can you help?

Comment: Check your IE browser compatibility !

Answer (score 0):

Most of the video types are not supported by IE various versions. Check here:

http://caniuse.com/#search=video